# How to use powershell to parse OU in a csv column with DistinguishedName data

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, ou, distinguishedname

I created this code to search for a group of users using a csv of emails:

```
$UserList = Get-Content C:\User\useremails.csv

foreach ($user in $UserList) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Emailaddress -eq $user}
    Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $user} -Properties name | 
    Select samAccountName, UserPrincipalName, DistinguishedName | 
    Export-Csv C:\User\accounts.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

It works, however, there's a lot of noise in the DistinguishedName column of the CSV.
Is there a way to parse that column to only get a specific OU or can this be done before exporting the CSV?

Here is an example of what I mean:

I have `useremails.csv`:

```
alex.jones@mail.com
bill.poppin@mail.com
cal.henry@mail.com
```

After I run the code, this is the output:

```
samAccountName  UserPrincipalName   DistinguishedName            
aj              aj@mail.com         CN=Alex Jones, OU=users, OU=finance, OU=company, DC=company, DC=com
bp              bp@mail.com         CN=Bill Poppins, OU=users, OU=tech, OU=it, OU=company, DC=company, DC=com
ch              ch@mail.com         CN=Cal Henry, OU=users, OU=company, DC=company, DC=com
```

If a user has an OU that shows a department, then thats the only OU I want. If a user only has users and the company name in OU then I only want the company name. But keeping the DistinguishedName column.

So this would be my desired output:

```
samAccountName  UserPrincipalName   OU         DistinguishedName                                                                                                               
aj              aj@mail.com         finance    CN=Alex Jones, OU=users, OU=finance, OU=company, DC=company, DC=com   
bp              bp@mail.com         tech       CN=Bill Poppins, OU=users, OU=tech, OU=it, OU=company, DC=company, DC=com
ch              ch@mail.com         company    CN=Cal Henry, OU=users, OU=company, DC=company, DC=com
```

Comment: Isn't the department of these users in their `department` attribute? `-Properties department` then and problem solved

Comment: Completely missed that. Thank you!